# Filemaker Pro: Create multiple entries of a table with Tab Control

Tags: tabcontrol, filemaker

I'm currently designing a Filemaker Pro database for a clinical trial.

The relationship between my different tables are done.
To simplify my issue, let say I've two tables.
I've a "info" table with the PatientID and general informations about this patient and I have another table with "day" results. The "info" and "day" tables are linked by a PatientID field. The "day" table has a variable "dayID" for discerning the collecting day of the data. We're going to collect data for this patient eight times (different days). The data consist of around 50 numbers.

I want to represent the entry for this patient with a header with the general info and under that a tab control with 8 tabs. In each tab, I'll have the same formatting/layout where I'll input the data.

So I want to be able to have a new entry in the "day" table for each tab. And for the moment I've failed to do that.

I have the multi-tabs tab control. And in each table, I've the same layout. But when I'm changing the value of variable A in tab "day3", it's changing also the value of variable A in tab "day0", "day1", and so on.

In fact, I've a exact copy of the same entry in "day" table in each tab. And not a new entry.

I've a solution, but not a clean and satisfactory one for me: create duplicates of "day" table for each day (let say "day0", "day1",...) and keep the relationship between them with PatientID.

So my questions are:

- Can we create multiple entries of the same table in different tabs on the same Tab Control ?

- If yes, how can I set a variable in a tab ? (I want to set the variable "dayID" to "day0" in tab "day0" and so on for each tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a portal in each tab, and specify a different (incrementing) initialRow for each each portal. Set Number of rows to 1. Add the relevant day fields to the portal.

So the first tab will show the first related record, second tab will show second, etc.

Sort the relationship by dayId, and pre-generated the appropriate day records.

Comment: Thank you so much Sam. I'm going to try to implement that this weekend.

Comment: I was able to implement the solution you proposed. It worked perfectly. Now I just need to be able to assign a value to a variable in each tab or pre-generated the 8 records (need to find how to do the latter in the user help).

Comment: Ok I didn't succeed in assigning a value to a field automatically. I'm going to ask another question, only for this issue.