# Filemaker Pro: Assigning a value to a field depending of the Tab

Tags: filemaker

It's a followup question about my project (designing a clinical trial form). My first question is here: [Filemaker Pro: Create multiple entries of a table with Tab Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225004/filemaker-pro-create-multiple-entries-of-a-table-with-tab-control)

In order to simplify, I've created a test FMP file. Here is the design of the database and the layout.
[Database structure](http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/812/help2a.png)
[Layout of the example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/137/help1i.png/)

For each patient, I'm creating a record in Patient Table - Patient_ID is the identifier. I'm going to put some general informations (here I used only the name).
On the other Table, labeled "Tableau_Data", I'm going to store some data - Data_ID is the identifier. The table Patient" and "Tableau_Data" are linked with Patient_ID.

The data will always be composed of the same field (in my example: "Turlututu") - in reality more than 50 parameters. We're going to collect the data for 5 days (so I've 5 tabs). Thanks to the help of Sam Barnum, I'm able to have a different record of "Tableau_Data" in each Tab, by using portals.

But I want to store in each record of "Tableau_Data" the tab it's coming from (field "Jour"). So I would like to have a way to set the automatically value of "Jour" depending of the tab: a script perhaps links to the portal or the field. But how ?

Ideally I would like to hide the "Jour" field.

By default, I can make a drop-down list and let the user set the value of this variable. I'd rather that. Not ergonomic and it could lead to error during the capture of the data.

Sam Barnum hinted that perhaps I could pre-generated the 5 records of Tableau_Data link to my Patient_ID. So with that I would know that records 1, 6, 11, 16, ... are for Jour=1 and records 2, 7, 12, ... are for Jour=2 and so on. But I do not even know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for your scripts and auto-enter calcs to automatically "know" what tab the user is on.  This is accomplished through the use of Layout Object Names and the function Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ).

In FileMaker each layout or groups of layout objects can have a "name". The uniqueness of the name is enforced by FileMaker so you can't possibly have 2 objects of the same name.  You set the Layout Object Name through the Inspector on the "Position" tab. Its at the top.

In your case you can give each tab a Name. This is accomplished by double clicking the tab in layout mode. It has a black border around it when it is selected. Then use the Inspector as described above to assign a name.

Once each of your tabs has a unique name.  You can use Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) to determine what tab the user currently has active.

Depending on your scenario you could do this with a script. Or it might be easier to just have the field in your database have an auto-enter calc set to "Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName )"  That way the database will record what Tab the user was on when the record was created.  Which is I believe your desired result.

Comment: If you really want to stick with the Tab idea, you can combine Todd's answer with my "You might also consider:" section, to auto-calculate the JourCurrent value based on the selected Tab, but you end up having to maintain 5 copies of all of your fields again.

Comment: Ok it seems it should work. But for some reason, the "Jour" field get set to the name of the previous field I was. For example, I've named the five "turlututu" field, "T_J1", "T_J2", ... and "T_J5". The Jour field get set to "T_J1" on tab 1, and so on. I decided to add another field "test" (variable "test" on the Tableau_Data table). And in fact if I'm selecting the field "test" first, the field "Jour" will be set to "test" and not "T_J1".

Comment: I do not know if the reason could be I'm using a portal per tab in order to have for each tab a different record of "Tableau_data" table.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. [link]http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/81855-getting-more-out-of-filtered-portals-7-creating-new-records-in-filtered-portals/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a small number of values for Jour (5, as you seem to indicate) it may be easiest for you to set up new relationships for each value of Jour--one for each tab.

To your Patient_ID table you would add one new field for each value of Jour. Each field would be a Calculation field with the value of the calculation being that particular value of Jour. For example, the Patient_ID table would have the following values:

```
Patient_ID::Patient_ID
Patient_ID::Nom
Patient_ID::Jour1 (Calculation value set to 1)
Patient_ID::Jour2 (Calculation value set to 2)
  ...
Patient_ID::Jour5 (Calculation value set to 5)
```

Then you would set 5 new relationships, linking both the Patient_ID and each Jour field, one at a time, to the new Table Occurrences of the Tableau_Data field (labeled, for this example, as Tableau_Data_Jour#:)

```
Jour1
Patient_ID::Patient_ID = Tableau_Data_Jour1::Patient_ID
Patient_ID::Jour1 = Tableau_Data_Jour1::Jour
```

All the way through:

```
Jour5
Patient_ID::Patient_ID = Tableau_Data_Jour5::Patient_ID
Patient_ID::Jour5 = Tableau_Data_Jour5::Jour
```

For each of the new relationships you will want to turn on "Allow Creation of Records in This Table By This Relationship".

Then you will change the fields on each tab so that the Jour 1 tab uses fields from the Tableau_Data_Jour1 table and the Jour 5 tab uses fields from the Tableau_Data_Jour5 table.

**You might also consider:**

The above should work fine, but it's ugly and creates a lot of work for you. If tabs are not a strict requirement, I'd recommend doing the following instead:

1. Create a new "JourCurrent" number field on the Patient table.
2. Create a relationship similar to the above, again allowing creation of new records on the Tableau_Data_Jour table:

   Patient_ID::Patient_ID = Tableau_Data_Jour::Patient_ID

   Patient_ID::JourCurrent = Tableau_Data_Jour::Jour
3. Make a new Value List with all values of Jour
4. Place the JourCurrent field on the layout, and set it to take values from the Value List as a pop-up menu.
5. Have the user select which Jour is appropriate for today's input from the pop-up menu instead of using a tab.

The advantage of this for you is that you only need to maintain each related field (Tableau_Data_Jour field) once, and you can add a new field once instead of once per tab.

Comment: I thought about the "might also consider". But I had to discard it quickly. First because the tabs is a requirement. I could have still use the pop-up menu in order to select "Jour". But the user do not want to have to enter that. The example I gave is a very simplistic one. In reality, I've nearly 15 tabs and, for the moment, 650 field per Patient_ID.